# Placeholder : position absolute not working with negative top value

Tags: html, css

I have an input, and it has a placeholder. I have successfully styled the placeholder, but when I try to move the placeholder to top when the input has focused its not working, I'm using position absolute, and top position with negative value.

It's my code looks :

```
<style>
    #wrapper {
      padding:40px;
      position:relative;
    }

    input {
      display:block;
      position : relative;
    }

    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: red;
      position:absolute;
    }

    input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      top:-20px;
      color:blue;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Engkus Kusnadi">
</div>
```

Here's my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/su2roqvc/2/

What I'm missing?

Comment: You can't set position to placeholder because it's not a block element. You can use labels instead of placeholders. And you can animate them as you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `labels` and it will work in **all** browsers!

---

**Upgate**

Added js for better behavior.

```js
var fields = $('.js-field');

fields.each(function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input');
  var placeholder = $(this).find('span');
  
  input.on('blur', function() {
    $(this).val() == "" 
      ? placeholder.show() 
      : placeholder.hide();
  });
  
  input.on('focus', function() {
    placeholder.show() 
  });
});
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 20px;
    left: 5px;
    color: red;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    transition: .3s ease;
}
input:focus + span {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="js-field">
  <input>
  <span>Placeholder1</span>
</label>
<label class="js-field">
  <input>
  <span>Placeholder2</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Just when i'm typing and input lost focus the text is hidden, and the span goes back to the down.

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi When input lost focus the text now is visible.

Comment: But when input lost focus the span go away

Comment: I think you understand the idea and can choose one of given answers.

Answer (score 4):

```css
#wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  position:relative;
}

input {
  position : relative;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

 
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
-ms-transform: translate(0, -20px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px); 
transform: translate(0, -20px);
color:blue;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px); 
transform: translate(0, -20px);
color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Engkus Kusnadi">

</div>
```

I'm not 100% with css3 yet, this doesn't work in Firefox yet but in Chrome your placeholder will pop up above the input.

hmmm researching the Firefox equivalent now

*edit
found an alternative solution that might work for you,
or lead to a solution. It works on Chrome and Firefox!
Good luck

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 14px/1.4 Sans-Serif;
}

form {
  width: 320px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
form > div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form input, form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  outline: 0;
}
form input:valid, form textarea:valid {
  background: white;
}
form input:focus, form textarea:focus {
  border-color: blue;
}
form input:focus + label, form textarea:focus + label {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
form label {
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s, top 0.2s, bottom 0.2s, right 0.2s, left 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  color: #999;
  padding: 7px 6px;
}
form textarea {
  display: block;
  resize: vertical;
}

form.go-up input, form.go-up textarea {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
form.go-up label {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
form.go-up input:focus, form.go-up textarea:focus {
  padding: 20px 6px 4px 6px;
}
form.go-up input:focus + label, form.go-up textarea:focus + label {
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form class="go-up">
  <h2>To Top</h2>
  <div>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" required>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="message" name="phone" required></textarea>
    <label for="message">Email</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Works only in Chrome.

Comment: Wow amazing code and works on Chrome, And it will be perfect if you add 
  transition:all 0.3s; efect for animation, Thanks very much!!

Comment: Can you make placeholder still show when im typing?

Comment: Placeholder is by definition only there until something else is put

Comment: hmm you'll have to go with what Karlisup said,
javascript would be my go-to for this, but there's a label trick of sorts that makes the label change when it's corresponding input is focused,
will come back when I find it if you're still stuck :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/uEHzD
might be useful, it depends how you are going to deploy your site.
I found the trick!
https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index2.html Beautiful examples, but ask for extra markup / style / js to be implemented.

Comment: Wow those examples are pretty, Op's implementation would now depend on whether he wants to go the Css label route or the Ultra Fancy but possibly expensive(performance wise) route.

Answer (score 1):

As @3rdthemagic already said there is no support for that.
I would suggest you to try playing with label, span or pseudo elements. [Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index2.html) has some great examples. Good luck ;)

[image: Typmanus example]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `top` `bottom` `left` `right` in `::-webkit-input-placeholder`. You can just use this style:

- font properties
- color
- background properties
- word-spacing
- letter-spacing
- text-decoration
  -vertical-align
  -text-transform
  -line-height
  -text-indent
  -opacity

You can use `input:focus[placeholder]`.

```css
#wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  position:relative;
}

input {
  position : relative;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}

input:focus[placeholder] {
  top:-20px;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Engkus Kusnadi">

</div>
```

Comment: Input changes position, not placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use line-height to move the text up, this code will support al browsers

```css
#wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  position:relative;
}

input {
  position : relative;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red;
  position:absolute;}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
  position:absolute;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: red;
  position:absolute;}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   line-height:1px;
   color:blue;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */ 
   line-height: 1px;
   color:blue;
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
   line-height:1px;
   color:blue;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   line-height:1px;
   color:blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Engkus Kusnadi">

</div>
```

Comment: Since the text is inside the textbox, you can't see it (fully) when it moves up